# Struggling with Javascript returning an array

Tags: javascript

Currently those two alerts at the bottom each return "undefined". I am not sure whether this problem is due to me trying to alert the wrong thing, whether I've just coded it wrong or what, help would be appreciated :).

```
var contents = [ "Loughborough University offers degree programmes and world class research.", "An alternative University", "Yet another University"]; 

function matchContents(contents,pattern)
{
    var c = pattern.toLowerCase();
    var d = [];
    var arraypointer = 0;
    for(var i = 0;i<=contents.length-1;i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0;j<=contents[i].length-1;j++)
        {
            if(c.charAt(j)>='a' && c.charAt(j)<='z')
                if(contents[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(c.charAt(j)==-1))
                    j=contents[i].length;
        }
        d[arraypointer] = i;
        arraypointer++;
    }
}

alert(matchContents(contents,"LU"));
alert(matchContents(contents,"other"));
```

Comment: `matchContents()` doesn't return anything

Comment: You should include a description of what your function is meant to do and what output you expected to see.

Comment: @JReyn what is matchContents suppose to do??

Comment: You are missing a return statement in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's simply a case of returning the array d.

```
var contents = [ "Loughborough University offers degree programmes and world class research.", "An alternative University", "Yet another University"]; 

function matchContents(contents,pattern)
{
  var c = pattern.toLowerCase();
  var d = [];
  var arraypointer = 0;
  for(var i = 0;i<=contents.length-1;i++)
  {
    for(var j = 0;j<=contents[i].length-1;j++)
    {
      if (c.charAt(j)>='a' && c.charAt(j)<='z')
        if (contents[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(c.charAt(j)==-1))
          j=contents[i].length;
    }
    d[arraypointer] = i;
    arraypointer++;
  }
  // function needs to return something
  return d;
}

alert(matchContents(contents,"LU"));
alert(matchContents(contents,"other"));
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still truggling a bit with it just returning 0,1,2 but I can work on that first and come back again if I'm struggling, thanks!